# What is d__92 in exception message?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, exception, datatable

I have 2 Linq queries that are filtering employees by country and department like this:

```
Dim employeesTableCountry = From employee In dataSource
                            Where employee.country = selectedCountry
                            Select employee

Dim employeesTableDepartment = From employeeDepartment In dataSource
                               Where employeeDepartment.department = selectedDepartment
                               Select employeeDepartment
```

I am trying to merge the two sets to make one final filtered set like this:

```
Dim finalTable = employeesTableCountry.Intersect(employeesTableDepartment)
```

However, when I do I get the following exception message:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'd__92`1[VB$AnonymousType_0`3[System.Data.DataRow]]' to type 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection`1[VB$AnonymousType_0`3[System.Data.DataRow]]'
```

What does the d__92 mean and how do I go about fixing this error?

Comment: Part of the name used to build an anonymous type. When you use lambads your compiler will need to create anonymous methods or types (if variables are captured). It'll name them like that (to be sure to do not conflict with your own names).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Is there a good way to handle this? Correct me if I'm wrong here, but shouldn't the two types be the same?

Comment: No, they're not. I assume employeesTableDepartment is a collectionion of...departments and employeesTableCountry is a collection of employees. How they can match? I'd use a Where for that.

Comment: You cannot intersect countries with departments. You can JOIN them, if that's what you meant - use a single query in LINQ instead.

Comment: No, perhaps my naming isn't the best. employeesTableCountry is a table of employee rows that have been filtered by the country column and employeesTableDepartment is a table of employee rows filtered by the department column. Then end goal is to have a table that is filtered by both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by manually typing my final table like this:

```
Dim finalTable As System.COllections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of System.Data.DataRow)
```